# Label animation inside a switch case c#

Tags: c#, animation, types, switch-statement, case

On the face of it it seems quite simple.
I have a switch case and if the condition is met I would like to print text to a label with a animation.
in this case a type writer animation.

I have already made the animation however I cant seem to integrate a similar version it into the switch case itself.
Any help?

Type Writer Animation code c#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int _charIndex = 0;
    string _text = "This is a test.";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _charIndex = 0;
        label1.Text = string.Empty;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.TypewriteText));
        t.Start();
    }


    private void TypewriteText()
    {
        while (_charIndex < _text.Length)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            label1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                label1.Text += _text[_charIndex];
            }));
            _charIndex++;
        }
    }

}
```

}

And the animation code needs to be placed into this:

Switch case code:

```
        void TestEngine(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
          case "Test":
          //Label animation code goes here
          break;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: side note: never use `Thread.Sleep(50);` for delay. instead use `Task.Delay(50).Wait();`

Comment: Have you confirmed that `e.Result.Text` ever evaluates to "Test"?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: No, don't use `Wait` - use `await Task.Delay(50)` or else use a `Timer`. `Waiit()` is a *blocking* call, making it effectively like `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yeah I probably shouldn't have used 'Thread.Sleep'. and @Saeb Amini a large proportion of the code has been cut and it does evaluate to "Text".

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: it might not be the best way to achieve his goal, but since OP is using a **dedicated** thread, there is nothing wrong to use `Thread.Sleep`. side note: never use `Task.Delay.Wait` combination - it's worse than `Thread.Sleep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - move the code in a method and call it from anywhere you want.
**Long answer**
While it works, it doesn't make sense because all the worker thread does is sleeping and then calling the UI thread. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` based approach would be much appropriate for this concrete case. The "modern" approach would be based on `async/await`. If you need flexibility, the last one is the best choice. But whatever you choose, you'll hit a reentrancy problem at some point and will need to handle it. The best would be to prepare some helper utility class and use it from anywhere. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new TestForm());
        }

        class TestForm : Form
        {
            public TestForm()
            {
                var label = new Label { Parent = this, AutoSize = true, Top = 8, Left = 8 };
                animateHelper = new AnimateHelper(label);
                int left = 8;
                foreach (var action in (ButtonAction[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ButtonAction)))
                {
                    var button = new Button { Parent = this, AutoSize = true, Text = action.ToString(), Left = left };
                    button.Top = DisplayRectangle.Bottom - button.Height - 8;
                    button.Click += (sender, e) => Execute(action);
                    left += button.Width + 8;
                }
            }
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && animateHelper != null) animateHelper.Cancel(); 
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
            enum ButtonAction { TypewriteText, RepeatText, Cancel }
            private void Execute(ButtonAction action)
            {
                // the original question
                switch (action)
                {
                    case ButtonAction.TypewriteText:
                        TypewriteText("This is a typewriter text animantion test.");
                        break;
                    case ButtonAction.RepeatText:
                        RepeatText("This is a repeating text animantion test.");
                        break;
                    case ButtonAction.Cancel:
                        animateHelper.Cancel();
                        break;
                }
            }
            AnimateHelper animateHelper;
            void TypewriteText(string text)
            {
                animateHelper.Execute(async (output, ct) =>
                {
                    bool clear = true;
                    try
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;
                        output.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                        for (int length = 1; ; length++)
                        {
                            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) return;
                            output.Text = text.Substring(0, length);
                            if (length == text.Length) break;
                            await Task.Delay(50, ct);
                        }
                        clear = false;
                    }
                    finally { if (clear) output.Text = string.Empty; }
                });
            }
            void RepeatText(string text)
            {
                animateHelper.Execute(async (output, ct) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;
                        output.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            for (int length = 1; length <= text.Length; length++)
                            {
                                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) return;
                                output.Text = text.Substring(text.Length - length);
                                await Task.Delay(50, ct);
                            }
                            for (int pad = 1; pad < text.Length; pad++)
                            {
                                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) return;
                                output.Text = new string(' ', pad) + text.Substring(0, text.Length - pad);
                                await Task.Delay(50, ct);
                            }
                            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) return;
                            output.Text = string.Empty;
                            await Task.Delay(250, ct);
                        }
                    }
                    finally { output.Text = string.Empty; }
                });
            }
        }

        class AnimateHelper
        {
            Label output;
            Task task;
            CancellationTokenSource cts;
            public AnimateHelper(Label output) { this.output = output; }
            void Reset()
            {
                if (cts != null) { cts.Dispose(); cts = null; }
                task = null;
            }
            public void Cancel() { DontCare(CancelAsync()); }
            async Task CancelAsync()
            {
                if (task != null && !task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    try { cts.Cancel(); } catch { }
                    try { await task; } catch { }
                }
                Reset();
            }
            public void Execute(Func<Label, CancellationToken, Task> action) { DontCare(ExecuteAsync(action)); }
            async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Label, CancellationToken, Task> action)
            {
                await CancelAsync();
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                task = action(output, cts.Token);
                try { await task; } catch { }
                Reset();
            }
            // make compiler happy
            static void DontCare(Task t) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The helped utility class worked perfectly.